# Sharepoint 2010 content type for a document library with number of folders

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I have a site collection which has many subsites in it, I would like to define a document library concent type and put 3 folders in it. Then use this content type to create document libraries in all the subsites, so when I need to modify something with the document library I can reflect the change to all the document libraries in the site collection.

I tried to create a content type; however there is no option to create a content type for a document library (or I could not find it).

Any suggestion is appreticated.

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to create a document library at the root of your collection configured as you like it. You then go into the library settings and save the library as a template. You can then provision new libraries off that template that will all be identical.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just have one follow up question, it is general for all the "template" concept in sharepoint, after I created an instant from a template (create a library from library template) if I modify the template is it going to be reflected to the instances of this template?

Comment: No, it will not update everywhere a library was created from. But if you have a content type hub, those changes would propigate out assuming the template used content types in the hub.

Answer (score 1):

A content type isn't a definition of a list or document library.

A contebt type is a definition of an type of item in the list or document library. Specifying which metadata (fields/columns) is availble for that item, which document template to use, which workflows are attached.

You can define content types which inherit from document or folder to put in a document library, but they can't controls which folders are available inside the document library.

As @PirateEric described what you want is probably a list template (or a list definition if you have a SharePoint developer). This can be combined with content types to control the above mentioned aspects.

But there is no feature in SharePoint which can help you make sure that all document libraries have the same sub folders, without writing special code (can be PowerShell)